# Request to understand the process

Tags: ethernet

How do I install Ubuntu in the apple iPad?

Second is it possible to use Ubuntu while using ExpressVPN?

Third do we have any hidden charges when using Ubuntu which is needed to be paid?

Comment: Hi Fred, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I found those answers just by doing a google search. In the future, please ask just one question and have a bit more of a look before posting on here. Thanks.

Comment: Just to emphasize: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: What @guntbert said :)

Answer (score 3):

> How do I install Ubuntu in the apple iPad?

Unfortunately, it's not really possible. See this answer: [How can I install Ubuntu on an iPad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6263/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-an-ipad)

> Second is it possible to use Ubuntu while using ExpressVPN?

Yes, absolutely. https://www.expressvpn.com/support/vpn-setup/manual-config-for-linux-ubuntu-with-openvpn/

> Any hidden charges when using Ubuntu?

Nope. [See this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/339145/182590)